# I use SQL Server and the following stored procedure always returns 0 , even when invalid input values are entered. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure is supposed to update the complaint table in the database and return 0 when it is successful. When I input valid values it correctly updates the table and returns 0. But when I input invalid values it returns 0 even there is no update.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateComplaintStatusDetails 
    (@_ID INT, 
     @_subID INT, 
     @_Status varchar(10))
AS
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   IF @_Status = 'InProgress'
   BEGIN
       UPDATE COMPLAINT
       SET status = (SELECT statusID FROM COMPLAINT_STATUS WHERE statusName = @_Status),  
           wipStartDate = GETDATE()
       WHERE complaintID = @_ID AND subComplaintID = @_subID
   END
   ELSE IF @_Status = 'Completed'
   BEGIN
       UPDATE COMPLAINT
       SET status = (SELECT statusID FROM COMPLAINT_STATUS WHERE statusName = @_Status),  
           finishedDate = GETDATE()
       WHERE complaintID = @_ID AND subComplaintID = @_subID
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       UPDATE COMPLAINT
       SET status = (SELECT statusID FROM COMPLAINT_STATUS WHERE statusName = @_Status)
       WHERE complaintID = @_ID AND subComplaintID = @_subID
   end

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
      GOTO errorHandler;
   
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   RETURN 0;

errorHandler:
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   RETURN -1; 
GO
```

Comment: Add the code that executes the proc and checks the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with @@ROWCOUNT in the past. I bet you if you return the @@ROWCOUNT value you will find that its always the same value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well know phenomena with the `@@ROWCOUNT` system variable. It resets its value.

Please try the following:

```
...
DECLARE @counter INT;
SET @counter = @@ROWCOUNT;

IF @counter = 0
...
```